# accessing array for javascript includes from config

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, include, config

I have a config_javascript.php file that has the array of all the javascript file paths to be included in the header:

```
$config['js_files'] = array
 (
'car' => array
 (
   'interior' => array
   (
      'js/interior.js'   ,
      'js/table_pagination.js',
      'js/libs' 
   ),
   'exterior' => array
   (
      'js/exterior.js'   ,
      'js/table_pagination.js',
      'js/libs' 
   ),
)
```

then in the controller I am loading this config file and trying and trying to access the array but it doesn't seem to like it:

```
 $this->config->load('config_javascript', true);
 $js_files = $this->config->item('js_files','interior');
```

when  I var_dump the array it's producing the bool(false);

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is it outputting?

Comment: For one, you aren't iterating through your array (let alone your array's array's arrays), meaning you're trying to include multiple `.js` files with a single `<script>` tag, and I'd be curious to see what it's actually outputting.

Comment: Jason, It outputs the empty javascript tags.

Comment: @pks That's because `js_files` array has a index of `car`. you need to get the `car` index by `$js_files = $this->config->item('js_files','car');` then access to *interior* by `$js_files['interior']`.